# .NET - Authenticate with JAVA API (SSL/TLS Error) using Certificates

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, ssl

So, for a few weeks I've been trying to make an .NET application to authenticate with an government Java API using an client certificate.

It was working fine for a couple of days and then I started to get this exception: "The Request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS channel.".

I know there is a lot of questions about this issue and I've tried all the solutions I could find, none has worked.

Here's the code:

```
        public async static Task<string> AuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var objT = default(string);
        HttpResponseMessage resultHttp;

        try
        {
            WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
            var certificate = CertificateHelper.GetCertificateFromLocalMachine();
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(CustomValidation);
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = /*SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls |*/ SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

            if (certificate != null)
            {
                //certificate.FriendlyName = "anAlias";
                X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();
                cert.Import(@"D:\Documentos\DUE\Certificados\eCPF\usa esse\jhonatan.pfx", "*******", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

                handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

                byte[] bytes = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12);

                handler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(CustomValidation);
                using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
                {
                    //! Uri base
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Endpoint);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CurrentCultureName", "pt-BR");

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Role-Type", "DEPOSIT");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Chrome");
                    resultHttp = await client.PostAsync("/portal/api/autenticar", new ByteArrayContent(bytes));

                    if (resultHttp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        objT = await resultHttp.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //! Tratamento de erro quando statuscode for diferente de 200 (Ok)
                        objT = await resultHttp.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Things I've tried:

1. Use ServerCertificateValidationCallback to set a custom validation method (I've tried 3 different methods)
2. Use SecurityProtocol to change protocols and test. If I set to an TLS protocol I get the HTTP error of "422 unprocessable entity".
3. Test ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue set to true or false, it made no difference.
4. Implement authentication using HttpResponseMessage, same error.
5. Implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508388/how-to-add-a-trusted-ca-certificate-not-a-client-certificate-to-httpwebrequest/12807434#12807434) solution, no success.
6. Implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033297/net-client-authentication-setup-using-httpwebrequest) solution, also with no success.
7. Combinations of multiple solutions found online, no success.
8. Pass client certificate in request as .pfx and .p12 files (using openssl to create different formats), same error.
9. Parse `DateTime` as common formats to check if it wasn't an date issue, no success.

**EDIT:** There was instability with receiving the SSL/TLS error before I started getting this error everytime. For example, a few days back, I was receiving this error all day long, but at night, when I got home and tested it again, it was working fine. It worked fine for about a week, then it started to display the SSL/TLS error again.

Comment: if it was working and then stopped, maybe certificate expired? Or their API changed to new version of TLS?

Comment: I've just checked the certificate, it is valid until December 2nd. I supossed they could have changed it. Now they're using TLS1.2, but running with this protocol in VS I get the 422 error, maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: take a look at version control history: what changed? Maybe encodings of files?

Comment: I have no access to the server's code, or version control, or any other information as it is a government's API, all I get from them is the documentation that I checked a hundred times. There is nothing in there about protocol's change.

Comment: I meant yours code source control. If you work in a team there could have been some encoding changing just because somene has different defaults

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm running this project solo. Nobody else changed the code.